# Como habilitar extensões do firefox no selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, extensão

Eu instalei uma extensão no firefox mas quando o selenium abre o firefox ele inicia sem a extensão, existe alguma forma de o selenium iniciar o firefox com a extensão que está instalada ou fazer ele "instalar" a extensão ao iniciar?
Estou usando a biblioteca selenium para python

```
options = Options()
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
url = 'https://www.google.com.br/'
self.browser.get(url.lower())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui descobrir, para adicionar uma extensão firefox no selenium em python é assim:

```
options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)   
browser.install_addon('caminho do arquivo .xpi')
browser.get('...')
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar options
aqui está a documentação necessária.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox.html